# Node.js Não consigo acessar uma propriedade da classe em método da própria classe

Tags: node.js, express.js

Fala galera,

esto começando a estudar Node.js, estou fazendo um exercício aqui estou deparando com o seguinte problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso, não estou conseguindo acessar a propriedade this.projects, que foi iniciada no método construtor, no próprio método store da classe.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Não insira seu código como imagem. Coloque-o como texto no corpo da sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Brother uma solução seria vc passar `projects` como parâmetro para o construtor, segue um exemplo:

```js
class ProjectController {
  constructor(projects) {
    this.projects = projects;
  }

  store(req, res) {
    return this.projects;
  }
}

console.log(new ProjectController([]));
```

Answer (score -1):

Voce precisa criar a variável primeiro para depois acessar ela com o this.

```
class TODOLIST {

public todo: [] = [];

constructor() {

 this.todo = ['task 1'];

}


 public addTodo(): void {
   this.todo.push(['task 2']);

 }

}
```

Comment: Isso é TypeScript, em JavaScript as propriedades podem ser declaradas e inicializadas dinamicamente dentro do construtor.